# Windows 10 IoT ActiveX usage

Tags: windows, raspberry-pi, activex, windows-10-iot-core

I want to start developing on Windows 10 IoT, but I would need to connect to 3rdparty devices over ActiveX or standard DLLs.

Is ActiveX supported on Windows 10 IoT? I could not find that info on microsoft webpage

maybe better rephrase :

**has someone successfully used on Windows 10 IoT for Raspberry Pi ActiveX (could be DLL) Library? 32bit Architecture?**

Answer (score 1):

As spoken with Microsoft people, Windows 10 IoT does not support ActiveX.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Are true console apps supported on Windows 10 IoT Core?**

True "console" apps aren't really going to be supported for the IoT core OS, headless or not. You can still deploy and run a standard win32 console app here, it just won't be connected to any on-device console. When running headless you should just get that black screen. When running headed the only supported UI is via the UWP UI stacks (XAML, HTML, DirectX).

[Found here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/faqs)

Please vote if this helped. The general vision is that they want you to to develop UWP apps to support their one app all devices ethos..

Comment: I'm not asking about console apps. I will give you sample of what I want to do : Windows IoT App, written in C#, with output to LCD Touchscreen display, connecting with help of ActiveX/DLL over the RS232 to the external device.


So again my question is : **has someone successfully used on Windows 10 IoT for Raspberry Pi ActiveX (could be DLL) Library? 32bit Architecture?**